# Add CUI references bug

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2012, reference, coded-ui-tests

i have a big problem. I need to develop CUI tests with VS 2012. I need to use the "old" (Version 10.0.0.0) CUI-dll's like "Microsoft.Visual Studio.TestTool.UITesting".
The problem is, VS **always** references the 11.0.0.0 Versions.
But the .csprj files does have the right entries like:

```
<When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' And '$(IsCodedUITest)' == 'True'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</When>
```

Deleting the 11.0.0.0, cleaning the solution and adding the 10.0.0.0 Version does not help.. VS Studio will always add the 11.0.0.0 Version...

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the conditional statement in the .csprj file will only going to use the version 10.0.0.0 references if the Visual Studio version is 10.0.

You can delete that section entirely and force the references to 10.0. This may or may not work (VS 2012 tries to be "smart" about references and use the latest version available).

You can also change the .csproj `<When>` condition and remove any reference to `VisualStudioVersion`. Again, this may or may not work.

Finally, in your app.config you can force a version override:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

This method can also fail when you're trying to force an older reference.

Regardless of the method you try, you'll want to make sure you back up your existing files so you can restore them if you accidentally mangle the project.

What is the reason you need to use the older versions? There may be better options for you by moving to the newer versions of those dlls.